# How can we work with multiple DBT projects

Tags: python, database, gitlab, dbt

can anyone share how to organise multiple projects in dbt , given the best practices. My present  abstract architecture hierarchy is as follows

```
Analytics 
--.dbt/
-----profiles.yml
--projects/
-----project_1/
----------models/
----------dbt_project.yml
-----project_2/
----------models/
----------dbt_project.yml
--tests/
-----projects/
----------project_1/
----------project_2/
```

To the point of creating models for either projects_1 or project_2 is working perfectly fine.

but the problem comes when i try to run the test (model unit tests) for project_2.when I run it gives the error
' no dbt_project.yml found at expected path in temp/project_1/ ...  ' (the unit tests that i am trying to run is for project_2)
however, the paths are absolutely correct but the lookup for dbt_project.yml is in wrong directory (in the temp directory). On the side note, some of the project_2 models does depends on few project_1 models.

can anyone share or reference where i can get the help to solve this sort of multi dbt project issue.

Answer (score 4):

Like many things, what you're asking here is two sub questions:

1. Is it possible?
2. Is it a good idea?

#### Is it possible?

While you didn't mention what data platform / dialect you are running on, yes, it is possible. Examples and recommendations here:

- [dbt Discourse:
  Can we use multiple Bigquery datasets (or projects) in the same dbt project?](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/can-we-use-multiple-bigquery-datasets-or-projects-in-the-same-dbt-project/769)

#### Is it a good idea?

I think Jeremy breaks out the main arguments for and against really well in this post reply:

- [dbt Discourse: Should I have an organisation wide project (a monorepo) or should each work flow have their own?](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/should-i-have-an-organisation-wide-project-a-monorepo-or-should-each-work-flow-have-their-own/666/2)

But if you've decided that you are already going to do this and don't want a monorepo and you're most interested in the "best" way to implement this, I'd recommend this post by Stefano:

- [Practical tips to get the best out of Data Build Tool](https://medium.com/photobox-technology-product-and-design/practical-tips-to-get-the-best-out-of-data-building-tool-dbt-part-1-8cfa21ef97c5)

TLDR: Yes, it's possible(ish). Best suggested methods are managing the  `generate_schema_name` / `generate_database_name` macros OR have low level models defined in packages that your main projects imports.